# How to open different menus depending on which app is frontmost?

Tags: imac, automation, shortcuts-app

I am trying to create something that opens different menus depending on which app is frontmost.

**For example**

- If I run it while InDesign is frontmost, I want it to open a menu containing the options "Open InDesign notes" and "Ask for help with InDesign". When selected, these options would open a word file with my notes and the InDesign support website respectively
- If I run it while the YouTube website is frontmost, I want it to open a menu containing the options "Open YouTube notes" and "Open Firefox notes" which, when selected, will open a link to a Google Doc with these notes.

**In short, the goal is to have a menu that gives me easy access to context-sensitive files and websites.**

## Research so far

I have tried to solve this problem using the Shortcuts app and its *Choose from menu* option.

I have found the *Is Frontmost* variable in the App category of shortcut inputs, see attachment. When I place it in an "If" block, however, I am unable to enter a variable to compare the frontmost app to.

1. Am I misunderstanding something about what *Is Frontmost* means here?
2. Is it possible to do something like this using Shortcuts?
3. If not, can I use Automator or would I have to start learning Applescript?

[image: Screenshot of a Shortcut workflow in the Shortcut app]

Comment: What is the thing that you're trying to do? It may be possible to automate the function directly, rather than emulating user interactions.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for your reply! I have clarified/generalized the question.